# Change Umbraco 'redirect to' to use 301 instead of 302

Tags: redirect, seo, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7.0.1 and want to change the default redirect behavior from returning a 302 to return a 301.

So I have a page: `/het-obam-perspectief/nieuws/` that redirects to `/nieuws/`.

I have set this up in the Umbraco CMS:

[image: CMS]

When the request comes back I get a 302 (as captured in Fiddler):

[image: Request in Fiddler]

Is there a way to reconfigure the default redirect behavior?  I've looked around the web and only seen instructions for changing redirect behavior when changing domains (stackoverflow.com/questions/16357712/umbraco-301-redirect-entire-site) or managing each redirect url manually (http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker), neither of which satisfies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, Umbraco's default behavior for the `umbracoRedirect` property is automatically a 302, and cannot be changed.

There's (2) different options that we have here.

1. Configure the redirect in either IIS or web.config for the 301
   using URL rewriting.
2. I found this package (haven't tested nor installed), but looks very
   promising. Seems to basially create a new doc type name
   `umbracoPermanentRedirect` and is of type `Content Picker`, which
   then does a 301.

[Umbraco Perm Redirect](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/permanent-redirect)

I'd go w/ option (2) since this is the behavior that acts like Umbraco's default property.

Please let me know how this goes b/c our company heavily uses SEO best practices and I'd get pinged on this 302 as well if I had need for redirects.

Apprec.